# Repeater's child controls will loss data in the ViewState when set a breakpoint in overrided method OnInit in the authored web control

Tags: viewstate

When I click button "Button1" after the first time, the repeater's child controls will lose data in the viewstate. I added a watch on `this.ChildControlsCreated`.  It is always true. This variable should initially be false.

```
The test code:
    /////////////////////CustomRepeater.cs/////////////////////
    public class CustomRepeater : Repeater
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e); **// Sets a breakpoint here**
        }
    }

    /////////////////////TestCustomRepeater.aspx/////////////////////
    <table>
    <cc1:CustomRepeater id="Control1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr><td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem) %></td></tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </cc1:CustomRepeater>
    </table>
    <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_OnClick"></asp:Button>

    /////////////////////TestCustomRepeater.aspx.cs/////////////////////
    Page_load()
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
             ArrayList dataSource = new ArrayList();
             dataSource.Add("a");
             dataSource.Add("b");
             this.Control1.DataSource = dataSource;
             this.Control1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protect void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Nothing to do, just to trigger a POSTBACK
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re-bind the Repeater after your postback. You can do it inside the method `Button1_OnClick`

Comment: But If I don't set break in method OnInit, no matter PostBack for one or more time, the repeater's child controls could be loaded normally from ViewState.